# C detect the last new line at the end of the file

Tags: c, file, fgetc

I can't detect the new line <del>after</del> just before the end of the file if the new line have text on the previous line.

I can detect the new line 4

```
1  some text
2  some text
3
4
```

But not the new line 3 with this type of file

```
1  some text
2  some text
3
```

(the number (1,2,3,4) are the lines, they are not in the file)

There is my sample code : (edit: code is updated with more relevant variable)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   FILE *fp;
  int ch;
  int i = 0;
  int line = 1;
  int column = 0;
  int tmp = 0; 
   fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
   if( fp != NULL ){
      while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        switch(ch) {

          case '\n':
              if(i == 0) {
                  column = tmp;
              }
              if(tmp != column) {
                printf("error\n");
              }
              tmp = 0;
              line++;
              i++;

              break;
          default:
              tmp++;
              break;
        }
      }
      fclose(fp);
   }
}
```

I don't understand why there is not output "error" in the second case.

Comment: fgetc() returns an "int" not a "char".

Comment: Does the 3 line case actually end with a `\n` or does it end with another character?

Comment: There is no "new line after the end of the file". The end of a file is just that: the end of a file. And from everything I see your code is apparently trying to detect a double-newline with no intermediate content, which is *not* present in the 3-line version, and *is* present in the 4-line version.

Comment: Really bad variable names `i`, `m`, `n` and `tmp`, and you're not even using `buff`. This is not fun to read.

Comment: this question is stupid... can you close it ?

Comment: this code has the problem that 'column' and 'tmp' are always = 0 when the check is made, so there will never be an instance where the error code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code counts the number of characters in the file before the first newline, and stores it as `n`.  Each subsequent time it reads a newline, it checks whether the number of characters read since the previous newline is the same as the number of characters on the first line (`n`), and prints an error message if not (which seems a bit odd).

Have you considered where the newlines are in your input, and what exactly the definition of a "line" is?  I think you will find that there are three newlines in the four-line text, and two in the three-line text.  That is, what your editor is presenting to you as the last line of the file is not itself terminated by a newline.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by understanding what a newline character is you will understand what's wrong
let's see the content of the file while showing the newline
the first file actually like this

```
1  some text\n
2  some text\n
3  \n
4  empty
```

not like this

```
1  some text\n
2  some text\n
3  \n
4  \n
```

and the second one is like this

```
1  some text\n
2  some text\n
3  empty
```